# What is the male:female ratio of gendered minifigures?

Tags: minifigures, history

For many years now, Lego has provided more detail on the face and bodies of minifigures. One of the effects of this is that the usually visually gender-neutral minifigures of my childhood (with the rare exception of a sloped piece as a dress) have been replaced by clear male and female faces and body shapes.

But in packing away my Atlantis sets to make room for my wife's new Super Star Destroyer, I've noticed that there's only one woman. And yet, oceanography and marine biology have some of the highest ratios of female graduates and employees in scientific fields, approaching 50%.

So of all the minifigures who are gendered (either explicitly by Lego in character biographies, or via secondary sexual traits like facial hair, or via cultural traits like wearing a dress or lipstick), what's the ratio of male to female minifigures? How does it break down year-over-year, theme-by-theme, and by recommended age group?

(As you might guess, there's an ideological agenda behind this question, and yes it's inspired by the ridiculous new "Lego Friends" line of figures. But what I'm most interested in right now is hard facts.)

Comment: If it's any help to your agenda, the first female Minifigure (a nurse) was released two months after the first male Minifigure, both in 1978. The precursor to the minifigure (the ones made out of bricks) also had male and female hair pieces in fairly even ratios (certainly I had about the same amount of both). But purely going by the Minifigures collections, male figures heavily outweigh female ones.

Comment: A lot of this is probably down to the market - Boys *tend* to prefer playing with (and watching) male characters (hence a lot of TV shows with male leads), while girls *tend* to accept playing/watching with either gender happily. This isn't to say that girls don't prefer to play with female characters, just that they tend to be more accepting of the imbalance. Certainly my sons are disappointed when we open a Minifigure packet and it's a lady in a dress.

Comment: Yeah, well, boys need to get over it. Maybe you need to talk to your sons about how not to be sexist.

Comment: I do, don't worry, that's also why I ensure we do occasionally pick one out - also they quite like the "action girls" - skaters, surfers, zoo-keeper etc., and that said, they seem to enjoy the Geisha head and hair - it's just the slope/dress they don't really like.

Comment: I did a quick check of the released sets in the Freinds theme. There are 23 female figures and one male figure (Peter).

Comment: In a rather cheeky way, I refer the honourable gentleman to [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1052/56) "My daughter loves to play with LEGO sets but she is really wants to play with pink or 'girl' LEGO", while we all do our best to educate our kids some things seem to get ingrained :(

Comment: There's worse than lady, there's C3P0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found [this](http://amodularlife.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/legos-female-oriented-products/#comment-2259) interesting comment by J on a blog post about [LEGO female oriented sets](http://amodularlife.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/legos-female-oriented-products/#comment-2259).

> I did a count of male and female mini-figures by theme in the 2011
> releases for which we have visual evidence. The modular house line
> always tends to be more balanced so there’s still potential there but
> the City theme is particularly bad this year. Here’s the results
> (aliens/creatures are excluded except where male-female
> differentiation exists:
>
> Alien Abduction: 9 male, 1 female
>
> Atlantis: 7 male, 1 female
>
> Castle: 15 male, 1 female
>
> City: 59 male, 5 female
>
> Collectible Mini-Figures: 37 male, 10 female (omit 1 alien)
>
> Creator: 2 male, 0 female
>
> Dacta: 33 male, 19 female
>
> Duplo: 16 male, 4 female
>
> Harry Potter: 20 male, 3 female
>
> Ninjago: 30 male, 3 female
>
> Pharaoh’s Quest: 9 male, 1 female
>
> Pirates of the Caribbean: 32 male, 4 female
>
> Star Wars: 43 male, 7 female
>
> Trains: 3 male, 0 female
>
> **TOTAL SYSTEM:** 299 male, 55 female
>
> **TOTAL DUPLO:** 16 male, 4 female
>
> **TOTAL:** 315 male, 59 female
>
> That’s greater than a 5:1 ratio and if you remove the Dacta and
> Collectible Mini-figure sets from the equation, you get a pathetic 8:1
> ratio (245 male, 30 female). I’ll say it again. If Lego wants girls to
> take interest in their products, they should make a better effort to
> include figures through which girls can identify.

The survey only takes into account 374 minifigures of the last year. It would be interesting to compare this data to minifigures released, 10, 20 and 30 years back to see how the gender ratio has changed.

---

### Collectable Minifigures Series 1-9 & Team GB

I've performed my own test, this time with Collectable Minifigures.
(Feel free to correct me on any of the ambiguous minifigures.)

> Series 1: 10 male, 2 female, 4 ambiguous (Tribal Hunter, Circus
> Clown, Robot, Demolition Dummy)
>
> Series 2: 12 males, 3 females, 1 ambiguous (Mime)
>
> Series 3: 11 male, 3 female, 2 ambiguous (Mummy, Space Alien)
>
> Series 4: 13 male, 3 female
>
> Series 5: 11 male, 4 female, 1 ambiguous (Small Clown)
>
> Series 6: 9 male, 5 female, 2 ambiguous (Classic Alien, Clockwork
> Robot)
>
> Series 7: 11 male, 5 female
>
> Series 8: 10 male, 5 female, 1 ambiguous (Evil Robot)
>
> Series 9: 10 male, 5 female, 1 ambiguous (Battle Mech)
>
> Team GB: 6 male, 3 female
>
> **TOTAL:** 91 male, 30 female, 11 ambiguous
>
> The ratio can roughly be simplified as 9:3:1 (m/f/a)

**[Download .CSV](http://pastebin.com/bXt2WpX9) <sup>[[?]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)</sup>**

### Collectable Minifigures REVISITED (December 2014)

All the genders of ambiguous minifigures have been confirmed using the gender pronouns used on [the official LEGO Minifigure minisite character page](http://www.lego.com/en-gb/minifigures/characters).

> Series 1: 14 male, 2 female
>
> Series 2: 13 males, 3 females
>
> Series 3: 11 male, 3 female, 2 ambiguous (Mummy, Space Alien)
>
> Series 4: 13 male, 3 female
>
> Series 5: 12 male, 4 female
>
> Series 6: 11 male, 5 female
>
> Series 7: 11 male, 5 female
>
> Series 8: 10 male, 5 female, 1 ambiguous (Evil Robot)
>
> Series 9: 10 male, 5 female, 1 ambiguous (Battle Mech)
>
> Series 10: 11 male, 5 female
>
> Series 11: 10 male, 5 female,  ambiguous (Evil Mech)
>
> Series 12: 11 male, 5 female
>
> Team GB: 6 male, 3 female
>
> The Simpsons: 13 male, 3 female
>
> The LEGO Movie: 10 male, 6 female
>
> **TOTAL:** 166 male, 22 female, 5 ambiguous

The share of unique female Collectable Minifigure from the main series have improved from 1/8 in Series 1 up to ~1/3 in Series 12. Collectable Minifigure that are not part of the standard series (Team GB, The Simpsons and The LEGO Movie) tend to vary.

**[Download .CSV](http://pastebin.com/2qgpeaWK) <sup>[[?]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)</sup>**

Comment: Yikes! The 12:1 ratio for City, which Lego has 100% creative control over and could easy just put in more women, is probably the most surprising/depressing.  This is very close to what I'm looking for - I'll leave the question open for a few days in case anyone can pull up good historical data, but otherwise this is a great answer.

Comment: I did notice the [Horizon Express](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10233-1#ui-tabs-3) set has exactly 50:50 ratio, including a female driver. Which is a start.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that only LEGO has the answer, and I'm sure they'd never tell. But for what it's worth, looking at the BrickLink.com stock, I came up with a ratio of 4:2:1 for  male:neutral:female heads.

I looked at heads because I feel like many figs aren't so cut-and-dried with respect to gender (or could be considered both/either), while it's pretty clear with heads where you stand. This doesn't take into account multiple copies of the same fig in sets, but it does take into account older minifig designs, which had a tendency to be less gender specific.

Anyway, in case anyone's interested, [here](http://annalsofspacetime.blogspot.com/2012/02/my-dear-lego-you-are-part-of-problem.html)'s a post with more details on my findings, including my sources and methods, as well as further musings on the gender-LEGO issue:

Answer (score 3):

This ratio has improved significantly in recent years, moving from 10% female mini figures in 2011. In 2017, almost 40% of figures in the City and Creative Expert ranges display female traits.

While there are many female figures in LEGO Friends, If you don't count duplicate character names,  there were around 38% male characters in 2017

A review of 2011-2016 can be found [here](https://ramblingbrick.com/2016/09/29/living-with-divercity-changing-depictions-of-gender-roles-with-lego-minifigures-in-the-post-friends-era/)
A summary of 2017 can be found [here](https://ramblingbrick.com/2017/10/31/minifigure-gender-distribution-2017-update/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this great info-graphic data](http://visual.ly/lego-minifigs), the male to female ratio is at **18:1**