# What different series are or have there been designed primarly for girls?

Tags: sets, theme

My daughter loves to play with LEGO sets but she is really wants to play with pink or 'girl' LEGO.  I have ordered a few of the new LEGO Friends sets but I was wondering what other LEGO themes' have been primarly designed for girls?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you've seen, the LEGO Friends sets are the latest theme aimed primarily at girls, however there are a number of current, and even more historical themes.

Other themes have included:

- [The Powerpuff Girls](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-The-Powerpuff-Girls) (2018 - ) - Uses Minifigs with custom heads, based on the popular Powerpuff Girls license
  [image: Bubbles Playground Showdown]
- [Elves](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Elves) (2015 - 2018) - Uses Minidolls similar to the Friends sets and continues the pastel colour themes (as of December 2018 all sets listed in the LEGO store are "Retiring Soon").
  [image: Aira's Creative Workshop]
- "Disney Princesses" now just [Disney](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-Disney) (2014 - ) - The sets based around the Disney Princess licenses use Minidolls as well, with a similar colour palette to Elves and Friends.
  [image: Sleeping Beauty's Royal Bedroom]
- [Belville](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Belville) (1994 - 2008) - used many standard LEGO bricks, but the figures were much larger than Minifigures.
  [image: A Belville set with horses.]
- [Clikits](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Clikits) (2003 - 2006) - a range of jewellery that can be used with LEGO System elements.
  [image: Some jewellery]
- [Disney Princess](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Duplo&subtheme=Disney%20Princess) (2012) - a sub-theme within DUPLO based on the popular Disney Princess range, featuring some of your favourite Disney characters.
  [image: Sleeping Beauty's Room]
- [Friends](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Friends) (2012) - based around the LEGO System elements, however the Mini-dolls are [slightly larger](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/959/56) than Minifigures.
  [image: Olivia's Invention Workshop]
- [Homemaker](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Homemaker) (1971 - 1974) - a very early theme based on LEGO system elements but before the minifigure
  [image: A Homemaker set]
- [Paradisa](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Town&subtheme=Paradisa) (1992 - 1997) - a sub-theme of Town, using standard minifigs.
  [image: A Paradisa set]
- [Scala](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Scala) (1979 - 1981, 1997 - 2001) - the original theme used LEGO System elements and was jewellery based, but the more recent theme bears very little resemblance to LEGO System elements, although some plates and other bricks are occasionally used.
  [image: Original Scala] [image: New Scala]

Set/Box images from [Brickset](http://www.brickset.com)

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that Clikits don't work with system. My partner and I have been adding them to our MOCs for the past year or so since we finally got some.

Comment: Also, don't forget about Paradisa which was a full System theme from the mid-90's. http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catID=71

Comment: Seems as though Lego has just released a new Lego Duplo Princess series.  It is Duplo Disney princess themed.  It has Sleeping Beauty, Cinderella, Snow White.  Themed lego for little girls now.