# Are there any African American LEGO minifigures besides the ones from the "Sports" basketball series?

Tags: minifigures

I was wondering if there were any African American LEGO minifigures besides the ones from the sports basketball series... I got a brown head from a LEGO Stormtrooper set instead of a black one. I then painted it. Do any other sets have them?

Comment: See also: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/287/132

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it's still a problem that Lego, inc. has (it seems like Lego's official position is that lego minifigs are non-racial - but they pretty obviously read as european or white to most people) -- interestingly Lego Duplo does not agree at all: http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-Education-People-4591514-Pieces/dp/B0085Y3JNS This is something I don't get. It bugs me as we've been transitioning our son to "little legos" and suddenly the worlds he has to build seem mono-cultural, un-diverse, and also a bit of a sausage party (he's gotten 6 or 7 sets, totalling about 20 minif

Comment: I found a few at https://minifigs.me

Answer (score 18):

There are a few on Bricklink, if you [search by part colour](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=1&pg=1&catXrefLevel=0&colorPart=88&catType=P&catID=238):

[image] [3626bpb212](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpb212)

[image] [3626bpb159](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpb159)

[image] [3626bpb749](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpb749)

[image] [3626bpb424](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpb424)

[image] [3626bpb214](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpb214)

[image] [3626bpb573](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626bpb573)

[image] [3626cpb1088](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626cpb1088)

[image] [3626cpb1124](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=3626cpb1124)

[image] [3626cpb1067](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626cpb1067)

[image] [3626cpb0906](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3626cpb0906)

[image] And the [standard smiley is also available.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bp01&colorID=88&in=A)

[If you search for the older Brown colour](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?partMin=&partMax=&figMin=&figMax=&itemDimX=&itemDimY=&itemDimZ=&searchName=Y&searchNo=Y&q=&catLike=W&catType=&catID=238&colorPart=8&itemYear=&pView=1&sortBy=N&sortAsc=A&sz=50) (instead of the current Reddish Brown) you find that there are basically only the very rare Lando head, as well as the old NBA heads.

Comment: nice search idea

Answer (score 9):

Minifigs from licensed sets are made to look like their license counterparts, so there are some there, most notably Star Wars [Mace Windu](http://www.brickset.com/minifigs/search/?query=Mace%20Windu) and [Lando Calrissian](http://www.brickset.com/minifigs/search/?query=lando%20calrissian) which have both been made in 4 different versions.

There's also one in Prince of Persia: [Seso](http://www.brickset.com/minifigs/?m=pop011), and maybe you can count the [gunner zombie](http://www.brickset.com/minifigs/search/?query=gunner%20zombie) from Pirates of the Carribean.

As for non-licensed sets, I don't see any other than the NBA ones.

Comment: Technically the NBA ones were licensed ;)

Comment: Color me wrong on that one

Answer (score 1):

2018 and still no better in the African American minifig or any kind of diversity. I need more diversity for my Brick Films. Although we did get Mae Jamison in the new Women of NASA set: [image: Mae Jamison in Women of NASA]

Comment: The main LEGO minifigure is yellow to offer a "non-denomination play experience", rather than trying to represent specific races and regions - Only licensed sets have "realistic" colours, and that sadly seems to reflect the make-up of the specific licenses - there have been few recognised women in NASA so there will be even less BAME women :( See also [female:male ratios of gendered mnifigures](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/946/56). There are three new sets based on Black Panther which add a further 4 heads.

Comment: The Jurassic World theme also included a limited number of BAME heads as well.